# How to find the integral of $\sin(x^{-1})$

Tags: calculus

How to calculate the integral of $\sin(1/x)$? I've tried integration by parts, but I just could find the wrong answer. What must I do?

Comment: According to W|A, the [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sin%28x^{-1}%29) is rather complicated.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

First, make substitution $p=\frac1x$, then integrate by parts with $u=\sin(p)$, $dv=\frac1{p^2}dp$.

You'll come across an integral of form $$\int\frac1u \cos(u)du,$$ which evaluates to cosine integral, as referenced in W|A answer given in comment.